# Decrypting DES with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, des

I'm trying to decrypt a DES-encrypted file from an external source with a known key and IV using OpenSSL (other libraries aren't really an option, as the application links against it already and I don't want to introduce new dependencies). It's a Qt application, so the data's coming in and out as QByteArrays.

Here's the code I have at the moment (set to write the decrypted data out to a file for inspection):

```
AmzHandler::AmzHandler(QByteArray encoded)
{
    QByteArray encrypted = QByteArray::fromBase64(encoded);
    QByteArray decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);
    QFile fred ("decrypted");
    fred.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
    fred.write(decrypted);
    fred.close();
}

QByteArray AmzHandler::decrypt(QByteArray encrypted)
{
    DES_cblock key = {0x29, 0xab, 0x9d, 0x18, 0xb2, 0x44, 0x9e, 0x31};
    DES_cblock iv = {0x5e, 0x72, 0xd7, 0x9a, 0x11, 0xb3, 0x4f, 0xee};
    DES_key_schedule schedule;
    unsigned char decrypted[encrypted.size()];

    DES_set_odd_parity(&key);
    DES_set_key_checked(&key, &schedule);

    DES_ncbc_encrypt((unsigned char * )encrypted.constData(), (unsigned char * )decrypted, encrypted.size(), &schedule, &iv, DES_DECRYPT);

    return QByteArray::fromRawData((char * )decrypted, length);
}
```

The output file for my test input is nonsense, and is not consistent across multiple runs. (I have a working implementation in Python, which is attached at the bottom of this post, to test against.) I'm not really sure what's going on; whether I've made some simple screwup in the conversions to char or am misusing OpenSSL.

EDIT: Solved. It turns out the line `DES_set_odd_parity(&key);` was missing. Add that and it works.

Here's working code in Python:

```
def AmzHandler(encoded):
    encrypted = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    d = pyDes.des(hex_to_str("29AB9D18B2449E31"), mode=pyDes.CBC, IV=hex_to_str("5E72D79A11B34FEE"))
    decrypted = d.decrypt(encrypted)
    f = open("decrypted-py", "w")
    f.write(decrypted)
    f.close()
```

Comment: This looks suspicious: `unsigned char *decrypted[encrypted.size()];`. It should either be a pointer, or an array.

Comment: @vhallac Okay. I've now tried both `unsigned char decrypted[encrypted.size()];` and (following [this](http://www.codealias.info/technotes/des_encryption_using_openssl_a_simple_example)) `unsigned char *decrypted; decrypted = (unsigned char *) malloc (encrypted.size());`. Both produce different sized output, but still in the order of hundreds of bytes and not apparently correct.

Comment: `QByteArray` will probably need the length of the array. There is no way to determine that from just the buffer address.

Comment: @vhallac Ah, okay. I've changed it to use QByteArray::fromRawData(), which takes an argument for the size of the data it's reading in. However, the output is still nonsense (whichever variant of the decrypted declaration I use).

Comment: The rest of the code looks OK. I would double check the key, if I were you. You may also try to double check your code by encrypting it yourself to ensure it can indeed decrypt before that.

Comment: @vhallac The key is correct; as I say, the Python code attached decrypts the file just fine. I shall try fiddling with encrypting as well, then.
Edit: The output is not consistent at all across multiple runs, so I don't think anything is getting written to decrypted...

Comment: @indiv Ah sorry, meant to do that, but it won't let you answer your own question until some time has elapsed, then I forgot. Doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was just a missing call to `DES_set_odd_parity(&key);`, which appears to be necessary for correct decoding with this implementation. Working code is as follows:

```
QByteArray AmzHandler::decrypt(QByteArray encrypted)
{
    DES_cblock key = {0x29, 0xab, 0x9d, 0x18, 0xb2, 0x44, 0x9e, 0x31};
    DES_cblock iv = {0x5e, 0x72, 0xd7, 0x9a, 0x11, 0xb3, 0x4f, 0xee};
    DES_key_schedule schedule;
    unsigned char decrypted[encrypted.size()];

    DES_set_odd_parity(&key);
    DES_set_key_checked(&key, &schedule);

    DES_ncbc_encrypt((unsigned char * )encrypted.constData(), (unsigned char * )decrypted, encrypted.size(), &schedule, &iv, DES_DECRYPT);

    return QByteArray::fromRawData((char * )decrypted, length);
}
```